# MongoDB: phantom records in $unwind results under heavy load

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a simple collection of elements like this

```
{_id: n, xs: [...]}
```

I'm trying to count total number of elements in all arrays

```
db.testRace.aggregate([{ $unwind : "$xs" }, { $group : { _id : null, count : { $sum : 1 } } }])
```

And it works great unless I start to do massive updates of this collection. Under heavy load of update operations I get wrong total - slightly bigger than it should be.

It can be easily reproduced.
First generate some test data

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
    db.testRace.insert({_id: i, xs: [i]});
}
```

Then simulate a lot of updates

```
while(true) {
    var id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);
    var obj = db.testRace.find({_id: id}).next();
    obj.some="change";
    db.testRace.update({_id: id}, obj);
}
```

And while it is running do aggregate unwind query. 
Without load I get right result - 1000000. But when there are a lot of updates I get bigger numbers, like 1001456.

And if I run query like this

```
db.testRace.aggregate([{ $unwind : "$xs" }, {$group: {_id:"$xs", count:{$sum: 1}}}, { $sort : { count : -1 } }, { $limit : 2 }]);
```

I get

```
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : 996972,
        "count" : 2
    },
    {
        "_id" : 997789,
        "count" : 2
    }
],
```

So it seems aggregate count some records twice.

Is it expected behaviour or maybe I'm doing aggregation wrong?

I tested on local mongodb instance, version - 2.4.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected behavior due to the way MongoDB handles read isolation. When you have a long running query (and an aggregation that reads every single document is a long running query) with updates to that data during the query it may impact whether or no the updated data is returned in the query - depending on what happens when, you could miss a document, receive it or receive it twice.

From the source code:

> Any data inserted, deleted, or modified during a yield that should be
>   returned by a query may or may not be returned by that query. The
>   query could return: nothing; the data before; the data after; or both
>   the data before and the data after.
>
> In short, there is no isolation between a query and an
>   insert/delete/update. AKA, READ_UNCOMMITTED.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/exec/plan_stage.h

Your aggregation query is yielding mid query, during which some of the data is updated. This impacts the results of the query.